Generating Tapir docs with OpenAPIDocsInterpreter for ZIO ZServerEndpoints
The problem: OpenAPIDocsInterpreter is written in terms of AnyEndpoint:
  type AnyEndpoint = Endpoint[_, _, _, _, _]

Our tapir-zio app is composed, of course, of ZServerEndpoints - ZServerEndpoints[Any, Any] as is typical.
There is no straightforward way I can see to translate ZServerEndpoints to AnyEndpoints. Runtime casting blows up with
[error] (server / Compile / run) Exception in thread "zio-fiber-4" java.lang.ClassCastException: class sttp.tapir.server.ServerEndpoint$$anon$3 cannot be cast to class sttp.tapir.Endpoint (sttp.tapir.server.ServerEndpoint$$anon$3 and sttp.tapir.Endpoint are in unnamed module of loader sbt.internal.LayeredClassLoader @520e8e13)
What is the solution for generating OpenAPI docs for ZServerEndpoints? Does anyone have a working example?

ZServerEndpoints is created by calling zServerLogic on a "normal" endpoint.
A good example can be found in the Github repo of Tapir - https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/sttp/tapir/examples/ZioExampleHttp4sServer.scala

Yeah, you're right. The way the app is structured now, that's hidden - no access to the plain endpoints. Refactoring needed.

The ZServerEndpoint is an alias for ServerEndpoint, using the ZIO effect:
type ZServerEndpoint[R, -C] = ServerEndpoint[C, RIO[R, *]]

Hence, you can simply pass a list of ZServerendpoints to the interpreter, using the OpenAPIDocsInterpreter.serverEndpointsToOpenAPI(...) method.
You can also access the underlying AnyEndpoint of a ServerEndpoint using its .endpoint method. E.g.:
val myEndpoints: List[AnyEndpoint] = myZServerEndpoints.map(_.endpoint)

